# "GetUserCollectionFromGroup" - Unable to create a schema from the results of the web service call

Tags: forms-services, infopath-rules

I'm trying to use a web service call on SP2010 using IFS. The call I'm trying to use is "GetUserCollectionFromGroup". I'm having trouble getting past the "Set sample data" popup. Everything I've tried has run into a roadblock. I've tried DOMAIN\username , group name and a other variations. All I'm trying to do is hide fields, sections, or buttons depending on what SharePoint group the user is in. Below is the generic error message along with the specific message as well. does anyone have any experience getting past this error? Thanks!

InfoPath was unable to create a schema from the results of the web service call-------

The SOAP response indicates that an error occurred on the server:
Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.
Group cannot be found.0x80131600

Comment: Are the groups set to be viewable by everyone or just the group members?

Comment: Group members and group owners of which I am both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to drill down to the actual subsite address when creating the UserGroup web service data connection, then it found the group I was looking for.